# UTF-16 string terminator

Tags: c, string, unicode, utf-16, unicode-string

What is the string terminator sequence for a UTF-16 string?

EDIT:

Let me rephrase the question in an attempt to clarify.  How's does the call to `wcslen()` work?

Comment: +1 Regardless of the fact that it will sollicit "wrong question" type responses, I love this type question because it is just the thing that google nor wikipedia will tell you.

Comment: Probably because it's too obvious. :-) BTW, C does not allow UTF-16 as the encoding for `wchar_t`, and cannot simply because it doesn't work with the C API for wide characters, which assumes each multibyte character corresponds to a *single* `wchar_t` value, not a sequence of `wchar_t` values. You're stuck with either UCS-2 or standard functions that fail to obey the requirements of the standard if you insist on making `wchar_t` 16-bit...

Comment: On every system I’ve every used, `sizeof(wchar_t)` == 4 bytes, or 32 bits.  I didn’t think it would work otherwise.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ has `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`, much to the annoyance of programmers who need to write cross-platform libraries that support Unicode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unicode does not define string terminators. Your environment or language does. For instance, C strings use 0x0 as a string terminator, as well as in .NET strings where a separate value in the `String` class is used to store the length of the string.

To answer your second question, `wcslen` looks for a terminating `L'\0'` character. Which as [I read it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character), is any length of `0x00` bytes, depending on the compiler, but will likely be the two-byte sequence `0x00` `0x00` if you're using UTF-16 (encoding [U+0000, 'NUL'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm))

Comment: Small point of trivia - .NET `String` objects have the length *and* a null terminator internally. That allows them to be used directly by interop functions which expect a terminator.

Comment: @Jon: had no idea, thanks. I assume I won't find that terminator if I go hunting `Chars`?

Comment: ...which I don't have direct access to, of course, and `ToCharArray` could do whatever it wants, including likely some native magic.

Comment: It seems that wcslen() must find at minimum, two 0x00 bytes since the character 'a' is UTF-16 encoded as 0x6100.

Comment: @Ray: that's true, if your environment uses UTF-16. My point was that a wide character, as used by `wcslen`, doesn't have a defined length. You're free to use (a made-up) UTF-128, and then `wcslen` would be looking for a string of 16 `0x00` bytes.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta can you correct your affirmation about .NET null termination of strings? We can definitely trust Jon Skeet here, and I also confirm .NET runtime terminates strings for interop purposes.

Comment: The wrong affirmation about missing null termination of strings in .NET has not been corrected yet.

Comment: Corrected the answer after verified the inactivity of the user.

Answer (score 5):

> 7.24.4.6.1  The wcslen function (from [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf))
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    [#3]   The  wcslen  function  returns  the  number  of  wide
>    characters that precede the terminating null wide character.
> ```

And the null wide character is `L'\0'`

Comment: `wchar_t null = L'\0'; printf("null is %d bits\n", 8 * sizeof null);` prints out that null is 32 bits.

Comment: @tchrist: you should be using `CHAR_BIT` instead of the magic 8. That `null` has the same size as each of the (4) elements of the array `L"foo"`.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any. String terminators are not part of an encoding.

For example if you had the string `ab` it would be encoded in UTF-16 with the following sequence of bytes: `61 00 62 00`. And if you had `大家` you would get `27-59-B6-5B`. So as you can see no predetermined terminator sequence.