# Get an UTF-16 string length from memory in python

Tags: python, memory, lldb, string-length, unicode-string

I need to read a **utf-16** encoded string that is stored in memory in a python script for LLDB. According to their documentation I'm able to use [ReadMemory(address, length, error)](http://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/_lldb%27-module.html#SBProcess_ReadMemory) but I need to know its **length** in advance.
If not python's **decode** function fails when it stumbles upon a character it cannot decode (even using the 'ignore' option) and the process stops:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u018e' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this? (either using a "python" or "lldb python" implementation). I don't have the original string's length.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code? It's great that you show the error, but please show full traceback and the sample code which is raising the error.

Comment: There are many ways to represent strings in memory. Does their doc tell you how they do it?

Comment: Here is a memory dump example or what I need to parse:

`(lldb) memory read 0x10142c838
0x10142c838: 61 00 62 00 63 00 64 00 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a.b.c.d.e.......
0x10142c848: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8e 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................`

Seems to be and UTF-16-le encoded string. But I'm not sure if it's always null terminated. I hope this gives a bit more insight.

Answer (score 2):

Is the string 0-terminated? If so, you could read 2 bytes at a time, until you encounter 0x0000, and then you'd know you have a complete string.

If you do this, you'd want to give yourself a constraint (e.g. "I will give up after reading - say - 1MB of data", in case you're running into corrupted memory).

Comment: I thought so too, but apparently there is no defined null [termination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923948/utf-16-string-terminator). Is there any function that evaluates this?

Comment: So if I understand, your task is to read a string whose length you don't know and with no known termination? That is a very badly defined problem. What if your valid string is followed by garbage that looks like characters? Are you OK with overly-aggressive printing? Are all characters in the string even going to be printable?